# Using Web 8 methods with Alchemy version 0.82 in Controller

Tags: core-service, a4t

I would like to get the Business Process Types in an Alchemy Controller.  I have the Alchemy version 0.82 VSIX and also Alchemy Core.  When creating a new StarterProject version 7.1 of the CoreService is referenced.  I remove it and reference the Web 8 CoreService Client DLL, and then use the below code for getting the Business Process Type.  However, I get the following failure.  Any ideas?

I see that the Web 8 Endpoint is not in the Core Service Client code here:https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/blob/master/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins/Clients/AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient.cs

I updated it with the name of the Web 8 endpoint, but no luck.

The Controller works fine on Web 8 when using Tridion 2013 methods, but not when using a Web 8-only method, such as getting a Business Process Type.  I'm working on a plugin that publishes, and I want to get a list of places to publish, which in Web 8 is the 'Purpose' of a BPT Target.  Sample code for that is below.

Error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Method Read is not supported on this
>   proxy, this can happen if the method is not marked with
>   OperationContractAttribute or if the interface type is not marked with
>   ServiceContractAttribute.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.GetMethodData(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService.Read(String
>   id, ReadOptions readOptions)    at
>   AlchemyBatchPublisher.Controllers.PluginController.GetPublishTargets(String
>   publicationUri)

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetPublishTargets/{uri}")]
public List<PublishTarget> GetPublishTargets(string publicationUri = "")
{
    if (!publicationUri.Contains("tcm"))
    {
        publicationUri = "tcm:" + publicationUri;
    }

    // Caching
    //if (pubTargets.ContainsKey(publicationUri))
    //    return pubTargets[publicationUri];

    List<PublishTarget> localPublishTargets = new List<PublishTarget>();
    PublicationData pd = Client.Read(publicationUri, new ReadOptions()) as PublicationData;
    var bptId = pd.BusinessProcessType.IdRef;
    var bpt = Client.Read(bptId, new ReadOptions()) as BusinessProcessTypeData;
    foreach (var targetType in bpt.TargetTypes)
    {
        PublishTarget pubTargetObj = new PublishTarget()
        {
            Name = targetType.Title,
            URI = targetType.Id,
            Purpose = targetType.Purpose
        };
        localPublishTargets.Add(pubTargetObj);
    }

    return localPublishTargets; 
}

public class PublishTarget
{
    private string _pubUri;
    public string PublicationUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _pubUri;
        }

        set
        {
            if (!value.Contains("tcm:"))
            {
                _pubUri = String.Format("tcm:0-{0}-1", value);
            }
        }
    }

    public string URI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you match the properties options while replacing the dll?

Comment: Do you mean of the referenced DLL?  Only the 'specific version' property of the reference was not the same, and I changed it but with no luck.  Any other properties to check?

Comment: I see an endpoint config in the source, wonder if this needs to be updated to add the Web 8 one?  https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/blob/master/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins/Clients/AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient.cs

Comment: Yeah, That's what I mean. and yeah may endpoint config needs an update, I didn't use core service with web 8 so not sure.

Comment: I added a new endpoint for Web 8 in the sourcecode here and compiled.  But how do I install this version as Alchemy?  https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/blob/master/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins/Clients/AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient.cs

Comment: This is alchemy core, so you need to build the deployable version after your changes and install it. But this is not the right way I think. A quick question, did you INSTALL the latest version of alchemy on the CMS machine from here http://www.alchemywebstore.com/downloads (so that it supports Web8)?  also, The code version you looked is "0.6.2" so its outdated.